# MediaPlayer.create(this,audio_file)

Tags: java, android

I am working for the first time in android studio with java. Can anyone please explain the difference between the two codes below.The first one works but the second one doesn't. why??

First Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer player;

    public void play(View view) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_file);
        player.start();
    }

    public void pause(View view) {
        player.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Second Code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rain);

    public void play(View view) {
        player.start();
    }

    public void pause(View view) {
        player.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second piece of code is trying to use the Activity before `onCreate` has been called (specifically, before your `onCreate` has called `super.onCreate`). You shouldn't do that, because your Activity isn't fully initialized at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in java the best way to initialze a variable is inside the contractor of the class like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer player;

public MainActivity() {
   this.player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_file);
}

public void play(View view) {
    player.start();
}

public void pause(View view) {
    player.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

The second code propably isn't working because when you initialize the variable outside the constractor or outside of some function the current class haven't been completely intialized yet and you pass as a variable the current class with the code "this"

Answer (score 0):

1. When MediaPlayer is declared global but created in a method. 
   So when you declare `MediaPlayer` in global but don't `initialize` it, Then it's just a `reference Variable`. 
   While doing this `MediaPlayer` is not ready, So when is it `Ready`?

```
public void play(View view) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_file); // <-- when you initialize it.
        player.start();
    }
```

When ever we use `.create` it  sets the MediaPlayer in `prepared`  State, (if the creation using `create` method is successful.)

2. Declaring and initializing MediaPlayer in Global.

When you write this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rain);
}
```

it means the media player is set to `prepared` state in start, There would be cases where you dont want your player to just use your resources. While doing this `declaring` and `initializing` it globally, it's using your resources when you don't need them.

While in previous example you just had made a `Reference` to the `MediaPlayer` But used it when ever you call `play()`